# Raspberry Pi ssh with laptop using putty

Tags: ssh, connection

How to find whether the ssh port is open and RaspberryPi have sshd running or not?

Comment: From the RPi itself? While logged in or in a script? From the network?

Answer (score 1):

The command `sudo service ssh status` or `sudo systemctl status ssh` show the status of ssh.

And to find out if the port is open, `nmap -p 22 --open -sV 172.21.2.0/24`, replace 172.21.2.0/24 with your network.

Answer (score 0):

> sudo raspi-config

Turn the service on or off as required. Use Fing on a phone that's connected to scan UP addresses then detect services running.

Comment: Turning the service on or off is not an answer to the question.

Comment: Running a scan with Fing from a phone on the same network will detect the IP and any running services. That will confirm it is running. Enabling/disabling (followed by a reboot) the service on the R-PI should be enough to know the service is running.